# Show image full screen then dialog

Tags: android

I have the image path and I want to show the image full screen with an alert dialog on top. What should I do?

1. Create Activity with image view and load the image path into a bitmap (using the sampling to avoid out of memory). Then set imageview to this bitmap and show alert dialog on top
2. Use the View Intent so the user pick his/her fav app to see the pic and show the dialog on top.

Now with the first solution, I know how to do but I am always worried about the size I should sample to avoid out of memory. Plus its extra work :)

With the second solution (I prefer), but I don't know how I would show dialog after the View Activity is called since it would be another app displaying the image unless there is a way I am missing

Any suggestion?

Comment: you should go with 1 option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show image in device specific height width....then you don't get out of memory for imagesize.

this is code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceWidth(Activity activity) {
        int deviceWidth = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceWidth = size.x;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceWidth = display.getWidth();
        }
        return deviceWidth;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceHeight(Activity activity) {
        int deviceHeight = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
        }
        return deviceHeight;
    }
```

you can use device height and width..and set this image in imageview..

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(viewHomeScreen);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        params.height = getDeviceHeight(activity);
        params.width = getDevicewidth(activity);
FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(viewHomeScreen);

        framelayout.addView(image, 0, params);
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I can use the hight/width when decoding the file to get the bitmap (by using sampling). Right?